# Rails: Linking two models that inherit the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, single-table-inheritance

This is a little bit tricky, so if you need more information, don't hesitate!

I have two models, `Store` and `Consumer` that are linked by two ways:

1/ `Store` and `Consumer` inherite from the same model `Profile`, because they share many attributes (name, location, email, web page,...). Here is the Rails AR code:

```
class Profile << ActiveRecord::Base
    # Attributes and validation rules go here.
end

class Store << Profile
end

class Consumer << Profile
end
```

This is the well known Single Table Inheritance (STI).

2/ In addition to STI, `Store` and `Consumer` are linked by a many to many relation:

- Store has many Clients (many consumers)
- A consumer is client to many stores

Because I need more attributes for this link (Store - Consumer), I have to create an extra model that will link them: `Client`.

Here are my final AR models:

```
class Profile << ActiveRecord::Base
    # Attributes and validation rules go here.
end

class Store << Profile
    has_many :clients
end

class Consumer << Profile
    has_many :clients
end

class Client << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :consumer
end
```

**Problem**

Using STI doesn't create store_id and consumer_id... we have only profile_id (because one real table `Profile`). So, how can I target the correct `Client` row having both store_id and client_id ?

Any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you're describing is not STI. STI is when two models are types of a thing: a Car and an SUV are types of Vehicle; a Cat and a Dog are types of Animal. In your case, however Stores and Consumers are not types of Profile. What you've got (at best) is a `has_one` relationship: a Store has_one Profile; a Consumer has_one Profile. You're probably looking at a world of maintenance pain trying to shoehorn STI onto your domain model here.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @TimothyHunkele: I'm just trying it now (seems we are connected !!). I'm seeing if STI is really necessary after reading Daniel explanations. Stay in touch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do is something like this. Also, I agree with Daniel Wright's comment.

```
class Profile << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :consumer
end

class Store << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
    has_many :clients
    has_many :consumers, :through => :clients
end

class Consumer << ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
    has_many :clients
    has_many :stores, :through => :clients
end

class Client << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :consumer
end
```

But if you'd like to make it work with what you have you could do something like:

```
class Profile << ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Store << Profile
    has_many :clients, :foreign_key => 'store_id'
    has_many :consumers, :through => :clients
end

class Consumer << Profile
    has_many :clients, :foreign_key => 'consumer_id'
    has_many :stores, :through => :clients
end

class Client << ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :consumer
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Timithy for your help and detailed code! It works terribly well.